# The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided

Tags: amazon-web-services, signature, amazon-ses

**I am using SES for sending email here is my code can you anybody tell me what is the problem ?**

**Is there anyone facing the same problem??**

*I have also check my credentials they are also correct.*

```
  $client = SesClient::factory(array(
      'version'=> 'latest',     
      'region' => REGION,
     'credentials' => array(
    'key'    => "AKIA***********",
    'secret' => "AoIM6Z/clu********************",
),
  ));

  try {
       $result = $client->sendEmail([
      'Destination' => [
          'ToAddresses' => [
              RECIPIENT,
          ],
      ],
      'Message' => [
          'Body' => [
              'Html' => [
                  'Charset' => CHARSET,
                  'Data' => HTMLBODY,
              ],
        'Text' => [
                  'Charset' => CHARSET,
                  'Data' => TEXTBODY,
              ],
          ],
          'Subject' => [
              'Charset' => CHARSET,
              'Data' => SUBJECT,
          ],
      ],
      'Source' => SENDER,
      // If you are not using a configuration set, comment or delete the
      // following line
      'ConfigurationSetName' => CONFIGSET,
  ]);
       $messageId = $result->get('MessageId');
       echo("Email sent! Message ID: $messageId"."\n");

    } catch (SesException $error) {
        echo("The email was not sent. Error message: ".$error-
    >getAwsErrorMessage()."\n");
   }

     }
```

Answer (score 2):

After so much googling I found out that my credentials are wrong. Just regenerate the credentials, try it again and it should work. Another thing is that the when key includes '/', it will not work, so if your key contains '/', regenerate it.